# Insert data into an NSMutableArray that belongs to a custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two custom objects: Movie and MovieTheater. In MovieTheater I have an NSMutableArray that I'm required to use to add movies. This is my code:

```
// theater 1
    MovieTheater* tempTh1 = [[MovieTheater alloc]init];
    Movie* tempMv1 = [[Movie alloc]init];

    if (tempTh1 != nil) {

        // set up a theather
        tempTh1.theaterName = @"Regal";
        tempTh1.theaterLocation = @"35335 Riverside,CA 92506";
        tempTh1.theaterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theatremain.ashx.jpg"];

        // set up movie 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------


        if (tempMv1 != nil) {

            tempMv1.movieName = @"The Zero Theorem";
            tempMv1.movieTime = @"SAT 18:30";
            tempMv1.movieImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zerotheorem.jpg"];
            tempMv1.movieTrailer = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtu.be/XpsJPOMfGSo"];

            // add movie to theater array
            [tempTh1.theaterMovies insertObject:tempMv1 atIndex:0];
        }



        // set up movie 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        Movie* tempMv2 = [[Movie alloc]init];

        if (tempMv2 != nil) {

            tempMv2.movieName = @"Welcome to the Jungle";
            tempMv2.movieTime = @"TH 16:30";
            tempMv2.movieImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcometothejungle.jpg"];
            tempMv2.movieTrailer = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtu.be/kRzSImxqQtA"];
        }

        // add movie to theater array
        [tempTh1.theaterMovies insertObject:tempMv2 atIndex:1];

        // set up movie 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        Movie* tempMv3 = [[Movie alloc]init];

        if (tempMv3 != nil) {

            tempMv3.movieName = @"The Bag Man";
            tempMv3.movieTime = @"TUE 15:30";
            tempMv3.movieImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bagman.jpg"];
            tempMv3.movieTrailer = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtu.be/mKBLfwVEKP8"];
        }

        // add movie to theater array
        [tempTh1.theaterMovies insertObject:tempMv3 atIndex:2];

        // set up movie 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        Movie* tempMv4 = [[Movie alloc]init];

        if (tempMv4 != nil) {

            tempMv4.movieName = @"Better Living Through Chemistry";
            tempMv4.movieTime = @"MO 16:45";
            tempMv4.movieImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"betterlivingthroughchemistry.jpg"];
            tempMv4.movieTrailer = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtu.be/qxHPqHIl11w"];
        }

        // add movie to theater array
        [tempTh1.theaterMovies insertObject:tempMv4 atIndex:3];

        // set up movie 5 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        Movie* tempMv5 = [[Movie alloc]init];

        if (tempMv5 != nil) {

            tempMv5.movieName = @"Blood Ties";
            tempMv5.movieTime = @"FR 19:00";
            tempMv5.movieImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bloodties.jpg"];
            tempMv5.movieTrailer = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtu.be/DI86othXjho"];
        }

        // add movie to theater array
        [tempTh1.theaterMovies insertObject:tempMv5 atIndex:4];


        // add the theater to the global array
        [cinemas insertObject:tempTh1 atIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"%@", tempTh1.theaterMovies);
    }
```

The problem I have is that [tempTh1.theaterMovies insertObject:tempMv1 atIndex:0]; does not add anything. The NSLog shows the array theaterMovies nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use -[NSMutableArray addObject:] ?

Comment: MovieTheater* tempTh1 = [[MovieTheater alloc]init]; - you should initialise theaterMovies there (in the -(id)init implementation) with an empty NSMutableArray or at any point later but before you are starting to add objects to it.

Comment: @singingAtom, I could use that, but insertObject: should work as well, right ?

Comment: @Nactus have you initialized the theterMovies array?

Comment: I don't see any sign of creating either of the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize tempTh1.theaterMovies in the init method of MovieTheater or just before you start adding objects with an empty NSMutableArray like

```
tempTh1.theaterMovies = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: sorry for the duplicate - is formulated my answer in the comments and then as an actual answer - its the same solution the others suggested :)

Comment: I actually glad you use the "answer" option instead of the comment, this way I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the `init` method of the `MovieTheater` class you need to allocate the array:

```
_theaterMovies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `theaterMovies` array is nil. You are probably never actually setting the property to point to an array. You'll probably want to do that in MovieTheater's `init` method.